# Can a package name contain Arabic text?

Tags: android, package, android-package-managers

Can the android application package name contain **Arabic** characters?

**Example**

```
 com.android.اختبار
```

I have checked this by creating a new project, the entered Arabic name was not seen in the package names of each Class.

Is there any official site stating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a package name with arabic characters.
Based on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#package)

> A full Java-language-style package name for the application. The name
>   should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters
>   ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual
>   package name parts may only start with letters.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new project in Android Studio, the applicationId exactly matches the Java-style package name you chose during setup. However, the application ID and package name are independent of each other beyond this point. You can change your code's package name (your code namespace) and it will not affect the application ID, and vice versa (though, again, you should not change your application ID once you publish your app). However, changing the package name has other consequences you should be aware of, so [see the section about modifying the package name](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id#modify_the_package_name).

And although the application ID looks like a traditional Java package name, the naming rules for the application ID are a bit more restrictive:

1) It must have at least two segments (one or more dots).

2) Each segment must start with a letter.

3) All characters must be alphanumeric or an underscore [a-zA-Z0-9_].

Answer (score 1):

You can localise everything in your app except the package name.
If you use different language in package studio doesn't take it into consideration hence you cannot see it in your app.

you can go through this link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization